# What determines the placement of the <Signature> tag when signing a SAML document?

Tags: xml, encryption, saml

In the examples I have found (Response, AuthnRequest, and LogoutRequest), and  the  tag appears inside signed node directly after . Is this simply dictated by the XML schemas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT, SAML schema states that the Signature element must come right after the Issuer element:
https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-schema-protocol-2.0.xsd

Comment: Thanks, yes. I did realize that and forgot to come back here to answer.